# selecting multiple max values

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this on a mysql database:

```
id | item
-----------
1  | 2
2  | 2
3  | 4
4  | 5
5  | 8
6  | 8
7  | 8
```

i want the result to be 3 record with the highest Item value

select max(item) returns only 1 value
how can i select multiple max values?
thank you

Comment: Are you that you've adequate explained the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query ...multiple max value selection. Help needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636758/sql-query-multiple-max-value-selection-help-needed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a derived table to get the maximum value and `join` it back to the original table to see all rows corresponding to it.

```
select t.id, t.item 
from tablename t
join (select max(item) as mxitem from tablename) x
on x.mxitem = t.item
```

Edit:

```
select t.co_travelers_id, t.booking_id, t.accounts_id 
from a_co_travelers t
join (select accounts_id, max(booking_id) as mxitem 
      from a_co_travelers
      group by accounts_id) x 
on x.mxitem = t.booking_id and t.accounts_id = x.accounts_id
```

Comment: hi, this works perfectly if i run it like this:
select `co_travelers_id`, `booking_id`, accounts_id from a_co_travelers join (select max(booking_id) as mxitem from a_co_travelers) x on x.mxitem = `booking_id`
but as i have to make a store procedure i have to add a condition:
where accounts_id = 6798
and this does not returns any record
any idea?

Comment: hi txs, the edited version is not returning any records eather

Comment: the inner query was missing a group by.added it

Answer (score 0):

If you use an 'aggregate function' without `GROUP BY` only one row will be returned.

You may use GROUP BY , with aggregate functions.

Here is **[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60f92/1)**

```
SELECT id,max(item) AS item 
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY id 
 ORDER BY item DESC 
 LIMIT 3
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[There is the graphical explanation](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1MIMZQWdrR3JZMk_deWktryUQoELJAtR_).
There is script mysql (low abstraction level, no inner join or sth)

```
select * from ocena, uczen where ocena.ocena = (SELECT MAX(ocena.ocena) FROM ocena WHERE ocena.przedmiot_id="4" and ocena.uczen_id="1") and ocena.uczen_id=uczen.id and ocena.przedmiot_id="4" and uczen_id="1"
```